# Android, java, view.setOnTouchListener

Tags: java, android

I had a `recyclerview` with an adapter and everything was cool. I added `view.setOnTouchListener` so that I could scroll this `recyclerview` along with animation and other elements on 1 screen from left to right. But after that, scrolling up and down broke in `recyclerview`, and `onclicklistener` on the elements inside it stopped working. What to do and how to fix this conflict?

At the moment I can put return false in the `public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) method;` instead of return `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent (event);` and get a working scrolling up and down back, but left-right stops working. I can do simultaneous scrolling as in ios, when scrolling of tablecloths and collections did not break when adding the svayp to the left-right.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                choseold = chosenow;
                chosenow = chosenow - 1;
                if (chosenow <= 0) {
                    chosenow = 5;
                    choseold = 6;
                }
                swipe();
            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                choseold = chosenow;
                chosenow = chosenow + 1;
                if (chosenow >= 6) {
                    chosenow = 1;
                    choseold = 0;
                }
                swipe();
            }

        });
        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);


        MyAdapterlang = new MyAdapterLang(MainActivity.this, yaziki1, yaziki2, flagi);
        RVlang.setAdapter(MyAdapterlang);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        RV1.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        MyAdapter = new MyAdapterApps(MainActivity.this, childs, childs2);
        RV1.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
    }
}

    class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

        private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

        public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            //return false;
        }
        /*public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    y1 = event.getY();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    y2 = event.getY();

                    float deltaY = y2 - y1;

                    if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
            }

            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        private float y1, y2;
        private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 50;*/

        private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

            private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                try {
                    float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                    float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                        if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (diffX > 0) {
                                onSwipeRight();
                            } else {
                                onSwipeLeft();
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void onSwipeRight() {
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
        }
    }
```

Here in ios, for example, is very simple and does not break the scrolling of collections:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft:)];
    swipeleft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swiperight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiperight:)];
    swiperight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperight];
}

-(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (self.currentnew <= 3) {
        self.whatpress = 1;
        [self.buttonnew sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}

-(void)swiperight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ((self.currentnew >= 1) && (self.currentnew <= 3)) {
        self.whatpress = 2;
        [self.buttonnew sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}
```

Here is a video:
https://2ch.hk/pr/src/1314926/15464190246250.mp4 https://2ch.hk/pr/src/1314926/15464193253190.mp4

Comment: Because you removed default touch listener that has been handling all the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to hook into default touch handling implementation you must return `false` here

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);//Idk if it is needed or not - out of scope
    return false;
}
```

Otherwise touch event will be considered as consumed and wont be propagated to other handlers (that handles scrolling, clicking etc. - all that stuff that stops working for you)